# I need two variables for a for loop in lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying Lua code to make a game in roblox and I want the cylinder to grow bigger every 0.0625 seconds to make a shockwave kind of thing and the scripts parent is the cylinder part.

```
for i = 0,5,1 a = 1,0,-0.1 do
    script.Parent.Transparency = a
    script.Parent.Size = Vector3.new(script.Parent.Size.X, script.Parent.Size.Y = i, script.Parent.Size.Z = i)
end
```

Comment: You need two loops, one is nested into another.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one control variable in a for loop. If you need more you need more loops or manage another variable in the loop's body.

It's not clear from your post what is required solution.

From [Lua Reference Manual 3.3.5: for statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

> ```
> for v = e1, e2, e3 do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local var, limit, step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
>    if not (var and limit and step) then error() end
>    var = var - step
>    while true do
>      var = var + step
>      if (step >= 0 and var > limit) or (step < 0 and var < limit) then
>        break
>      end
>      local v = var
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```

Make sure you understand this and derive a solution for your problem from it.

Assuming you want to degrade transparency value between each size increase you should use a nested loop.

```
for size = 1, 5 do
  script.Parent.Size = Vector3.new(script.Parent.Size.X, size, size)
  for transparency = 1, 0, -0.1 do
    script.Parent.Transparency = transparency
  end

end
```

I skipped size 0 because I assume that size 0 objects are not visible so why alter their transparency?

Note that I fixed a syntax error in your code.

```
script.Parent.Size = Vector3.new(script.Parent.Size.X,
                       script.Parent.Size.Y = i, script.Parent.Size.Z = i)
```

would cause a `')' expected near '='` error as you may not assign values in a function call.